# Encoding two values in a short URL token

Tags: c#, .net, encryption

I am working on a short URL app, where the token must identify 2 values: the link ID and the user ID. Ideally this token should be short.

For example, considering the URL http://sho.rt/15qq6, the token "15qq6" must identify the link and user ID.

I guess one option is to insert both values in a table and use the auto-generated ID as a token, but I would rather not. I would prefer a solution involving encryption.

How could I use the .NET encryption classes for such purpose, if possible? Many thanks for your help.

Comment: How long are your user ids and link id?

Comment: If you use encryption you will definitely get a much longer string than you want

Comment: They are both integers. I guess it's OK if the token doesn't turn out to be too short. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not clear on how short you want your code. I posted some code online [to encrypt any number of query arguments](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/security/encrypting-query-arguments).

The result could be shortened by base64-encoding the result. That might still not be short enough for you though. (Note that I didn't base64-encode it because I had some concerns about base64 encoding is case-sensitive.)

Another approach would be to come up with a code that consists of an ID into your database and some sort of checksum. If the user tries modifying the ID, you could detect this. However, this approach may not be that secure since it might not be that hard to figure out how to create your own checksums.

Comment: +1. Your sample should be enough to see how to use encryption. Also for putting back to Url I'd use either base32 encoding (url-safe and ignores letter case changes) or at least modified base64 that use only Url-safe characters.

Comment: @Alexei: Yes, base32 might be a nice compromise.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer is "You can't", at least, not easily.

Encryption typically doesn't change the length of the data being encrypted.  So if you take the URL and UserId that you want to encode and encrypt them you'll end up with a token that's the same total length.

You could try compressing the data before encryption, but there's not a lot of redundancy in a single URL, and this won't buy you much.

You culd hash the data to give you a shorter result, but there's no way to reverse this process to get your URL and userId back.

If it's a short token you need then the only real option I can think of is a lookup table on the server, using the token as the key.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you understand exactly how Encryption works.

Encryption is just a technique for making it difficult to decode the response, without knowing the original encryption key.

The encrypted data is at least as long as the original data, if not larger. 
There is no viable way of encoding a URL into a smaller amount of data, that's still valid in a URL.

Use a database for this, that's what they're for.

Edit: D'oh, Andrew beat me to it with a better response after editing.

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like the [RNGCryptoServiceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider.aspx) to generate a unique set of characters.  Use a few constants strings holding a range of characters like "a" to "z", "A" to "Z", and "1" to "9".  Save the randomly mixed case alphanumeric string with the original URL and UserID.

Answer (score 1):

Generate random token and save link and user id in db for this token. It is security enough.

Comment: How do you know whether it is secure enough?  Maybe he works at your bank and is using these URLs to give you quick access to your checking account.

Comment: Random token don't contain any information, and random token don't be picked up. For better security can use crypto random.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need encryption, than simple combination of [Convert.ToBase64String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524.aspx) and [BitConverter.GetBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8z32tce.aspx) will give you reasonable string. Note that Base64 uses some non-url cahnracters, so consider replacing them in result [WikiPedia Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Variants_summary_table), or using Base32 encoding.

```
int first =1234;
int second =789;
var encoded = Convert.ToBase64String(
        BitConverter.GetBytes (((ulong)first<<32)+(ulong)second));
```